# Analogue of conic sections for the permutohedra, associahedra, and noncrossing partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, discrete-geometry, sequences-and-series

Slicing cones in various ways with a plane generates conic sections identified geometrically as hyperbolas, parabolas, or ellipses and algebraically, when suitably rotated, as certain rescaled quadratic polynomials, or forms, in two variables.

The refined face partition polynomials of the permutohedra (OEIS [A049019](https://oeis.org/A049019)) and associahedra (or Stasheff polytopes, [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437)) and partition polynomials for noncrossing partitions ([A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264)) can all be algebraically related by re-scaling the associated monomials per the calculus of compositional and multiplicative inversion of power series, so this represents the algebraic analogue of the rescaling of the quadratic equations for conics.

Which geometric structures, such as possibly the noncrossing hypertrees of McCammond, brick polytopes, or simply polygons, when "sliced" in different ways, provide  representations of permutohedra, associahedra, and noncrossing partitions?

Ancillary question: Is there a geometric complex (possibly the Whitehouse simplicial complex, related to phylogenetic trees, or the trees themselves) that can be associated to Lagrange (compositional) inversion of exponential generating functions (i.e., formal Taylor, or divided powers, series) and can be incorporated in this geometric scheme if one exists?

Comment: Related:  https://oeis.org/A102537; Einziger, (http://pqdtopen.proquest.com/doc/750317016.html?FMT=ABS) Incidence Hopf algebras: Antipodes, forest formulas, and noncrossing partitions;
J. McCammond, (http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~jon.mccammond/papers/index.html) Noncrossing Hypertrees;
J.-C. Novelli, J.-Y. Thibon,  (http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5962) Hopf Algebras of m-permutations,(m+1)-ary trees, and m-parking functions;
E. Tzanaki, (http://arXiv.org/abs/math.CO/0501100) Polygon dissections and some generalizations of cluster complexes.

Comment: Related to ancillary Q: https://oeis.org/A134991

Comment: See "Hopf monoids and generalized permutohedra" by Aguiar and Ardila https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07504

Comment: Related "Relating the associahedron and the permutohedron" by Tonks https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/80c9/c4cef0a9c7cec3de650e6d8fb7ca9f5f966b.pdf

Comment: Cf. "Hopf Algebra of the Planar Binary Trees" by Loday and Ronco.

Answer (score 2):

2-truncated cubes provide the "slicings" to generate the associahedra or permutahedra.

See "[Upper and lower bound theorems for graph-associahedra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1631)" by Buchstaber and Volodin,  "[Cubical realizations of flag nestohedra and Gal's conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5478)" by Volodin, and "[Geometric realization of $\gamma$-vectors of 2-truncated cubes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0398)" by Volodin.

There is a video of a cube being truncated to form a 3-D permutahedron (truncated octahedron) at a [website](https://www.google.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fveraviana.net%2Fconvex-semiregular-polyhedra%2F&source=hp&ei=7ILJYMfnB5Km-wTJw7aYCg&oq=https%3A%2F%2Fveraviana.net%2Fconvex-semiregular-polyhedra%2F&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBADUOwiWOwiYN1faABwAHgAgAGnAYgBpwGSAQMwLjGYAQCgAQKgAQGwAQA&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp#sbfbu=1&pi=https://veraviana.net/convex-semiregular-polyhedra/) maintained by Vera Viana.

Comment: And "The diagonal of the associahedra" by
Naruki Masuda, Hugh Thomas, Andy Tonks, Bruno Vallette https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08059

Comment: See also "Diagonals on the Permutahedra, Multiplihedra and Associahedra" by Samson Saneblidze, Ronald Umble https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209109

Comment: "Direct families of polytopes with nontrivial Massey products" by
Victor Buchstaber and Ivan Limonchenko https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02221

Comment: See also p. 16 of "Toric Topology of Stasheff Polytopes" by
Buchstaber

Comment: See Fig. 1.4 on p. 18 of "From permutahedra to associahedra,
a walk through geometric and algebraic combinatorics" by
Vincent Pilaud http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~pilaud/documents/reports/habilitationVincentPilaud.pdf

Comment: From "Convex Polytopes and Enumeration" by Rodica Simion: "... the permutohedron, the associahedron, polytopes arising as intersections of cubes and simplices with half-spaces ... ."

Comment: See also "Combinatorial 2-truncated Cubes and
Applications" by Buchstaber and Volodin in the book Associahedra, Tamari Lattices and Related Structures: Tamari Memorial Festschrift (editors: Müller-Hoissen, Pallo, Stasheff).